# Huge memory Allocation when using EPPlus Excel Library

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

**Context**

I have been using [EPPLUS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) as my tool to automate excel report generation, using C# as the client language of the library.

**Problem:**

After trying to write a really big report (response of a SQL Query), with pivot tables, charts and so forth, i end up having a `Out of Memory Exception`.

**TroubleShooting**

In order to troubleshoot, i decided to open an existing report that has 138MB, and use the `GC` object to try to take a peek on what's happening with my memory, and here are the results.

```
ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage (new FileInfo (@"PATH TO THE REPORT.xlsx"));
ExcelWorkbook wb = pkg.Workbook;
```

Garbage Collection Results, before the second line of code, and after.

[image: The ammount of memory in use is too damn high]

So, i have no idea what to do from now on. All i am doing is opening the report, which is consuming roughtly 10 (9.98 actually) times the report size itself, on memory.

The ~138MB of the excel file, takes up 1.370.817.264 bytes of RAM.

**Update One:**

There's a fairly recent [beta version of EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.0.0-beta2) that's out that has on it's changelog:

```
New Cell store
* Less memory consumtion
* Insert columns (not on the range level)
* Faster row inserts
```

After updating the Nuget, i still have the same exception, that is thrown after the first line, instead of being raised on the second line.

Answer (score 5):

Modern Excel files, ie, Xlsx files are zip-compressed, and often achieve compression down to 10%. I just uncompressed a 1.6MB file I generated using a similar tool and found it extracted to 18.8 MB of data.

You've got a 0.138 GB file that is using 1.370 GB of memory, which is almost exactly 10%. The uncompressed representation in memory is what is eating your memory.

If you're curious, you can use a tool like 7-Zip to extract the Xlsx files, or you can rename the file to end in .zip and browse it in Windows.

Comment: I have just extracted the ~138MB report (.xlsx) and it ended up having 0.99 GB on disk. Can you think of any "cheaper" way of doing this?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins You could manually create the XML documents using Streams instead of having their entire contents in memory at once. At some point you'll have to zip it all up, you can use a library that handles bigger files though to handle that part. Unfortunately, you'll miss the ease of use of Excel. I guess the real problem is "why do you have such massive Excel documents"?!

Comment: @mason I am doing a project for one of the "Big Four" Telecom companies of Brazil (can't tell its name). This report, is responsible for showing a subset of it's clients, which as you expect, is huge.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins - One thought that occurs to me is that you might be able to split the data between multiple Xlsx files. Excel supports some sort of inter-file linking. I just tried playing with it but wasn't able to get it to work exactly like how you'll need, but it's something to experiment with.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins: but the report will not actually show 140MB of data, will it? It sounds like you show some aggregation results only. You you a) create those aggregation results outside of excel then only keep the aggregated data that is really needed in excel or b) set up excel to access the db itself (via mircosoft query, connect to MS SQL Server Analysis Services or something similar)? This way you will have small excel files and keep the data in the database. Also, what advantage to you gain when using epplus to create an excel file instead of using excel to create excel files?

Comment: @BenSchwehn I am retrieving data out of an Amazon Redshift Database, which i can't setup excel to access the data directly. Also, using EPPlus is one of the two ways i know to automate excel generation, the other being using the Excel COM Object. The problem with COM objects, is that they don't behave well half of the times, raising weird errors, exceptions and having a more than poor performance for larger reports.

Comment: @BenSchwehn - using excel itself for writing data is sensible for only the tiniest files. Excel COM is cumbersome, and very slow. Epplus is certainly the right way to go here; nothing but data partitioning is going to fix the fact that he has a huge data set to write out.

Answer (score 1):

As I've encountered this too, and found no real solution, I've had to come up with the solution by myself.
It comes as a new library: https://github.com/danielgindi/SpreadsheetStreams.net

This is based on taking a very old piece of code of mine, that supported csv and xml, refactor the interface, add xlsx support, and publish as a standalone library.

This is *not* a replacement for EPPlus or other spreadsheet manipulation libraries, this one is just about *streaming* generation of reports. Not all excel features are there also.