# EPPLUS 4.1 OutOfMemory Exception for "xlsx" files but not "xls" files

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus, epplus-4

I'm using Epplus 4.1 to read the content of uploaded files and insert them into the database, pretty simple operation actually.

However I got reported a bug that for some reason one file is getting out of memory exception when I create the package.

```
        try
        {
            this._package = new ExcelPackage(file);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            ValidFile = false;
            log.Error(e);
        }
```

Exception: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Inner Exception: null

But when I upload the same file but save it as "xls" (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 worksheet) it goes without a hitch!

**Note that the file in xlsx format has 27mb and when I save to xls it has 40mb**

Does anyone knows what might be going on? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: Well you could try to debug it and see what the cause of the problem is or raise an issue on the [codeplexpage](http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic). But im pretty sure you would need to provide an example .xlsx for anyone to provide you with any further information. But since xlsx is a zipped format, you probably hit the 4GB barirer with a 40mb file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge memory Allocation when using EPPlus Excel Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562034/huge-memory-allocation-when-using-epplus-excel-library)

Comment: @CSharpie Thank you for the comment.

Comment: It's just weird that the xls file can run without a problem and the xlsx doesnt. By the way I couldn't find the answer in the mentioned post, I even sent an email to the OP to see if he manage to fix it.

Unfortunately I can't send the data to anyone, it's sensitive information.

By the way, I tested with bigger files even and the problem seems to be just with this one.

Comment: The mentioned post doesnt specifically solve your problem, but antiduh describes what is probably the same issue you are having.