# Finding a row in excel meeting multiple conditions with c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have a c# winform program which opens up an excel spreadsheet to update. I want the program to search for a row meeting multiple conditions (i.e. the number 5 in column E, and the word "butter" in column G) so I could activate the cell [row,A]. I'm familiar with the search methods within excel, but I want to do this programmatically with c#. How can I do this with preferably a few methods?

Comment: There are several different libraries for loading Excel files in C#. Which one are you using?

Comment: System. Office. Excel. Interop.                                   And vstoee100 and 90

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, there are many libraries you can use in C# to perform operations with an Excel spreadsheet. Some of them even require you to have excel installed such as using "COM" to communicate with the excel process itself and send commands to it via it's own windows bound APIs.

My personal favorite is a library, that even though has [known issues with memory consumption being too high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562034/huge-memory-allocation-when-using-epplus-excel-library), is good enough for most uses: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

You can refer to their [getting started page](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) to check a few examples of how to use their methods, but its pretty self-intuitive.